# Integration by substitution not working?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been working on a set of problems for the past 6 hours and I'm about to explode from frustration! Either my book has errors, Wolfram Alpha is broken or integration by substitution does not work!

I'm trying to solve the following ODE:
$$
\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{1-20kh+kh^2}{20h-h^2},\text{ where }k=0.01
$$

Here is what I have (the first line is the ODE I'm trying to solve, if it's unclear):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dh}{\mathrm dt}&=\frac{1-20kh+kh^2}{20h-h^2}\\
\frac{20h-h^2}{1-20kh+kh^2}\,\mathrm dh&=\mathrm dt\\[5pt]
\frac{20h-h^2}{1-0.2+0.01h^2}\,\mathrm dh&=\mathrm dt,\text{ since }k=0.01\\[5pt]
\frac{100\left(20h-h^2\right)}{100-20h+h^2}\,\mathrm dh=\mathrm dt\\[5pt]
\int\frac{2000h-100h^2}{(h-10)^2}\,\mathrm dh&=\int\mathrm dt
\end{align}$$

Let $u=h-10$
So, $h=u+10$
And, $\mathrm dh=\mathrm du$

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\int\left(\frac{2000(u+10)}{u^2}-\frac{100(u+10)^2}{u^2}\right)\,\mathrm du&=t+c\\[5pt]
\int\left(\frac{2000u}{u^2}+\frac{20000}{u^2}-\frac{100(u^2+20u+100)}{u^2}\right)\,\mathrm du&=t+c\\[5pt]
\int\left(\cancel{\frac{2000}u}+\frac{20000}{u^2}-100-\cancel{\frac{2000}u}-\frac{10000}{u^2}\right)\,\mathrm du&=t+c\\[5pt]
\int\left(\frac{10000}{u^2}-100\right)\,\mathrm du&=t+c\\[5pt]
-\frac{10000}u-100u&=t+c\\[5pt]
-\frac{10000}{h-10}-100(h-10)&=t+c\\[5pt]
-\frac{10000-100(h-10)^2}{h-10}&=t+c\\[5pt]
-\frac{100\left(100+(h-10)^2\right)}{h-10}&=t+c\\[5pt]
-\frac{100\left(100+\left(h^2-20h+100\right)\right)}{h-10}&=t+c\\[5pt]
\frac{100\left(h^2-20h+200\right)}{10-h}&=t+c
\end{align}$$

But according to Wolfram Alpha, that isn't the correct answer.

- http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28100x%2820-x%29%2F%28x-10%29%5E2%29+with+respect+to+x

And according to my book's solution manual, this is the answer (same as Wolfram Alpha's answer):

> (b) Letting $k=1/100$, separating variables and integrating (with the help of a CAS), we get $$\frac{100h(h-20)}{(h-10)^2}\,\mathrm dh=\mathrm dt\;\text{and}\;\frac{100\left(h^2-10h+100\right)}{10-h}=t+c$$

The equation on the right in the solutions manual is the same as what Wolfram Alpha outputs. However, it seems that there's a typo in the equation on the left. It should be $\frac{100h(20-h)}{(h-10)^2}$ instead of $\frac{100h(h-20)}{(h-10)^2}$. If we input that left equation in Wofram Alpha, we don't get the solution on the right:

- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28100x%28x-20%29%2F%28x-10%29%5E2%29+with+respect+to+x (see comments in the graydad's answer)

What's going on? Why isn't my method giving me the right answer?

For reference:

- [question a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxzC6.jpg)
- [solution to question a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4KDw.jpg)
- [my solution to question a (which is correct)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IphTe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Actually, my substitution method works just fine. I do get the answer, but after some algebraic manipulation. Continuing from where I left off:

[image]

Amateur mistake! I think the typo in the solutions manual was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram and your books solution manual are in agreement. If you scroll down on the page of the Wolfram link you provided and look at the "alternate forms" section, you'll see exactly the same quantity that your book provided. One other difference is that you didn't tell Wolfram that your quantity was equal to some $\text{d}t$. It should be obvious that the integral of $\text{d}t$ is $t$. As for the constants that are gained on both sides of the equation (let's say $x_0$ and $t_0$ respectively), you can always subtract the constant from the LHS and just let it hang out with the one on the RHS so that $c = t_0-x_0$. As for where your math is going wrong, you may be able to get a "step by step" breakdown from Wolfram, another website, a friend or another MSE user. If I have the time to look at your work more later I can try to find it.

Comment: Look at the signs in front of of the alternate form on wolfram alpha versus the solutions manual. They're different, no? EDIT: Alright, let me know what you find! Thanks!

Comment: @Georan They are equal.  The answer in your book absorbs the $-1$ into the denominator by swapping the order of subtraction.

Comment: Ah, yeah I missed that. But, if you look at the equation on the left in the solution manual and you put it in wolfram alpha, it gives a different answer from what they have : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28100x%28x-20%29%2F%28x-10%29%5E2%29+with+respect+to+x . Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Georan I just noticed that the Wolfram link you provided in your question has your equation entered incorrectly. In particular, you typed in the numerator $20-x$ when it should be $x-20$. The link you provided in your most recent comment on my answer does appear to have the equation entered correctly, and *that* one does differ to differ by a $-$ sign from what your book says. I'd guess your book has a typo, and the numerator should be $h-10$ instead of $10-h$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Well, at least one confusion is out of the way!

Comment: How come your integral in the beginning is 100h(h-20)/(h-10)^2 ? On my 4th line, I came to something different: 100h(20-h)/(h-10)^2 . Did I make a mistake between line 1 and 4?

Comment: @Georan Sorry for any confusion! I think I did some hasty math. I deleted it for now until I clean it up. You for sure copied down the problem correctly? That is, what you have posted at the top of this page is exactly the ODE?

Comment: Yes, in question a), they ask us to find the differential equation and in question b), they ask us to solve it (i'll update my answer with some pictures). But regardless, when we plug in the initial value problem to Wolfram, it gets the correct result, but for some reason, my substitution method doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.